# Print FlowDocument + Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, flowdocument

I'm trying to print a `FlowDocument` which consists of an `ItemsControl`. I would like to split it up automatically on multiple pages if necessary. Currently I'm unsure why it does output a blank page. I've tried to look up similar questions, though they had not much information I could make use of.

My `FlowDocument` looks like this:

```
<FlowDocument x:Class="PrintFlowDocument.Views.GoWithTheFlow1"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PrintFlowDocument.Views">
    <Paragraph>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding StringList}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Paragraph>
</FlowDocument>
```

The `DataContext` of the `FlowDocument` is set upon instantiation and the `StringList` property is (currently) initialized in the constructor of the VM.

```
GoWithTheFlow1 flow = new GoWithTheFlow1() { DataContext = new FlowVM() };
flow.PageHeight = 1122.5196850393702;
flow.PageWidth = 793.70078740157476;

//---

ObservableCollection<string> _StringList;
public ObservableCollection<string> StringList
{
    get { return _StringList; }
    set { if (_StringList != value) { _StringList = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(() => StringList); } }
}
```

To print the document, I'm using a `XpsDocumentWriter` and print it for test purposes to the XPS printer.

```
var writer = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(XPSPrinter);
writer.Write(doc); //IDocumentPaginatorSource...
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong ? Why does it not display the ItemsControl + content ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there is [no support for data-binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd569761.aspx) in `FlowDocument`.

I'm discarding this solution/try and use an existing solution (`DocumentPaginator`) for now.